# Convert a string with a carat to a number (and evaluate)

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a column of imported numbers in format `123.4`
The decimal here actually should signify "to the power" of i.e. `^`

I want it to display in another column as the evaluated value. Where `123.4` would display as `228886641`.

I used the `SUBSTITUTE` command to replace the decimal with `^`, giving me `123^4`, which looks good but it is not a number. If i use the `VALUE` command on the output from `SUBSTITUTE` (the text string `123^4`) though I get the `#VALUE!` error.

How do I get from `123.4` to `228886641`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=INT(A1)^MID(A1,SEARCH(".",A1)+1,1)` or you risk the power being either .4 or 40 in your example.

Comment: I already tested your first response and it worked, what issue do the enhancements correct?

Comment: LOL, I was just trying to figure that out, why it did not work on the others

Comment: Noted, but Negatives are not a problem

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I found is:

```
=(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))^(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,100))
```

Uses the `.` as delimiter to decide what is the power.

**EDIT:**
Or a bit shorter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)^MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,100)
```

This one accepts negative powers and powers up to 100 characters long (negative sign included).

Not sure what you mean when you say 'returns text' though. It seems to work well for me.

Comment: this works but it is a little longer and returns text rather than a number.

Answer (score 0):

Use formulas such as `int` to get the integer part.

So:

> = int(A1) ^ (A1 - int(A1))

Beware: if number is negative, int may round downwards when you would want it to round upwards. If you have negatives, use an `if` to add 1.